# How to create a mongoose schema that makes sure that user provide only one subcategory?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a product for an e-commerce website. I want to make sure that the user provides only one sub category for the product. But the way I have implemented my schema user can create product even without providing any sub category and I want the user to select only one sub category. My current schema is like this:

```
category: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
   enum: {
     values: [
       "men",
       "women",
       "kids",
     ]
   }
},

subCategory: {
  men: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ["shirts", "t-shirts", "trousers", "jeans"],
    },
  },
  women: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ["shirts", "t-shirts", "trousers", "jeans"],
    },
  }
  kids: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ["shirts", "t-shirts", "trousers", "jeans"],
    },
  }
}
```

But right now even if I don't provide any `subCategory` the product is still created. Please help me out with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I used pre validate middleware in mongoose to solve this.

```
productSchema.pre("validate", function (next) {
  if (!this.subCategory.men && !this.subCategory.women && !this.subCategory.kids) {
    return next(new Error("Please provide atleast one value for sub category"));
  }
  if (
    (this.subCategory.men && this.subCategory.women && this.subCategory.kids) ||
    (this.subCategory.women && this.subCategory.kids) ||
    (this.subCategory.men && this.subCategory.kids) ||
    (this.subCategory.women && this.subCategory.men)
  ) {
    return next(new Error("Please provide only one value for sub category"));
  }
  next();
});
```